# How to deselect selected row

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

How can i deselect a row when another row is selected here i have this in my cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
if ff.isVisitedd{
        cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
    }else{
        cell.accessoryType = .None
 }
```

And this in didSelectRowAtIndexpath

```
if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
        let selectedRows = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows! as? [NSIndexPath]
        let ff: Card!
        ff = cards[indexPath.row]
        ff.isVisitedd = true
        cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding, you want to remove the check mark of a previously selected cell when another cell is selected. Since in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, you already correctly set up the `accessoryType`, any new cell will have a correct check mark status. The only work left is to remove the check mark on existing cells, if any. You can get the existing cells from the `visibleCells` of the table view. One possible solution is:

```
tableView.visibleCells.filter { $0 != cell }.forEach { $0.accessoryType = .None }
```

If you prefer for-loop:

```
for visibleCell in tableView.visibleCells where visibleCell != cell {
    visibleCell.accessoryType = .None
}
```

Comment: Where will this go

Comment: Inside the `if let` @benfo

Comment: I've just updated the answer to match the `tableView` variable name and Swift version.

Comment: Yea i got that.

Answer (score 1):

## Swift 3

You can use the `deselectRow(at:,animated:)` method.

## Swift 2

`deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath:,animated:)`

Comment: Yea that will deselect it when it is tapped..i want to deselect when another row is tapped